# capturing jquery Radiobutton list selected values

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get value of selected item using JQuery in a radio button list. I have 2 radio button lists and I am getting value from 1st radio button list with out any issues. But When I select 2nd dropdown, It shows the same first dropdown result in alert.

Please suggest

```
  $("#<%=RBLTechnology.ClientID%> input").change(function () {

                var ProjectArchitecture = $("input[@name=RBLTechnology]:checked").val();
alert("Selected Project Architecture Layer is " + ProjectArchitecture );
                           });

            $("#<%=RBLforService.ClientID%> input").change(function () {
                var ServiceLayer = $("input[@name=RBLforService]:checked").val();
                alert("Selected Service Layer is " + ServiceLayer);

            });



 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RBLTechnology" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="ASP.NET webforms">ASP.NET webforms</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="ASP.NET MVC">ASP.NET MVC</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="SilverLight">SilverLight</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="WPF">WPF</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>


     <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RBLforService" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="Class Library Service">Class Library Service</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="Web Service">Web Service</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="WCF Service">WCF Service</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="WCF RIA Service">WCF RIA Service</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please go over jQuery [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).
from what i see so far:

```
$("#<%=RBLTechnology.ClientID%> input"), $("#<%=RBLforService.ClientID%> input")
```

needs to be

```
$("#<%=RBLTechnology.ClientID%>"), $("#<%=RBLforService.ClientID%>")
```

and

```
$("input[@name=RBLforService]:checked"), $("input[@name=RBLforService]:checked")
```

needs to be

```
$("input[name='RBLforService']:checked"), $("input[name='RBLforService']:checked")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblRequestType">
        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="value1">Value1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Value2">Value2</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

You can control listitems  (checked or not) like this;

```
var radio0 = $("#rblRequestType_0");
var radio1 = $("#rblRequestType_1");

if (radio0.checked){
// do something
}
if (radio1.checked){
// do something
}
```